# How to upload all files from directory to s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client

I am writing node js script which should send images from directory `'/images/'`, to the **amazon s3**. I know the **knox** is very good library, but how can I upload all files from directory, with the old file names. I can probably use **fs** module, get all names and upload it with `for` loop. Is there any function in **knox** which can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knox does not provide any functionality for client-side file handling.
You need to find your files manually and upload them one after one.

Unfortunately its impossible to upload multiple files once. The problem is that S3 requires that you send the Content-Length header for every file.

Comment: so is it possible to do it with console script? I am talking about headers.

Comment: I mean uploading files one after one

Comment: Sure, that's what loops are for. Do you need further help?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the command line tool s3cmd ( http://s3tools.org/s3cmd ) ? If you really want to do it in node.js, you can spawn a process to execute s3cmd in your javascript code.